# set relations in evailable full table in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, orm, model, relationship

i create an migration as below :

```
  public function up()
{
    //
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('parent')->nullable()->unsigned();;

        $table->string('category_name');
        $table->text('category_lable');
        $table->timestamps();
});
    Schema::table('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->foreign('parent')
            ->references('id')->on('categories')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');
    }) ;
}
```

and that migration is seeded by this way :

```
   Category::create([
        'id' => 1,
        'parent' => null,
        'category_name' => "root"
    ]);

    Category::create([
            'id' => 2,
            'parent' => 1,
            'category_name' => "something"
         ]);

    Category::create([
        'id' => 3,
        'parent' => 2,
            'category_name' => "something"
            ]);
    Category::create([
        'id' => 4,
        'parent' => 2,
            'category_name' => "something"
            ]);

    and etc ...
```

also this is my model that is self Referenced :

> ```
> class Category extends Model
> {
> public function getchildren() {
>     return $this->has_many('App\Category' , 'parent');
> }
> public function getparent()   {
>     return $this->belongs_to('App\Category' , 'parent');
> }
> ```
>
> }

in the tinker when i try to get some node parent or children , an error accured.

error :

> BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getparent()'

or

> BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getchildren()'

where is my wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

First, the relationship methods should be *camelCase*:

```
public function getchildren() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Category' , 'parent');
}
public function getparent()   {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Category' , 'parent');
}
```

Second, the errors are occuring because you probably requested these relationships the wrong way. You are calling these methods on a `Builder` instance, instead of an `Model` instance.

It is supposed to look something like this:

```
$category = Category::first();

var_dump($category->getchildren, $category->getparent);
```

Or:

```
foreach(Categories::all() as $category) {
  var_dump($category->getchildren, $category->getparent);
}
```

Anyway, if you could share the code you entered in Tinker, we can identify the problem exactly.

**Edit**

You should rename your methods to `children()` and `parent()`, so without *get* prefix.

Also, to retrieve this relationships directly, call them as a *property*, instead of a method:

```
$model = Category::findOrFail(26);

// this will return Builder instance
var_dump($model->children(), $model->parent());

// this will return the return a Collection of children
var_dump($model->children);

// this will return the parent
var_dump($model->parent);
```

Difference is ().

Comment: tnanks @jan-willem for your attention . here is mine :  $cat = Category::findOrFail(26) and then :  $cat->children()

Comment: it return null :(( ($model->children)